# How many elements of order 7 does the group $G = (\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z})^{99}$ have?

Tags: group-theory

The full question is:

How many elements of order 7 does the group $G$ have, (a) if $G = \mathbb{Z} / (7^{99}\mathbb{Z})$? (b) if $G = (\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z})^{99}$? How many subgroups of order 7 does $G$ have in each case?

I think $G = \mathbb{Z} / (7^{99}\mathbb{Z})$ has $\phi(7) = 6$ elements of order 7 and 1 subgroup of order 7, since it is cyclic, but b) is a little unclear, particular what form $G = (\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z})^{99}$ takes.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: replace "99" with "2", "3" or "9" and try solving it.

Some explanation: Given your work in the first case and my familiarity with the problem, I am sure you could solve this if you felt you could get your hands on any element of the group. But also, I am suggesting [such a basic problem solving technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It) that it would be remiss for you to make it further in your education without reaching for it by instinct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is my answer for a) wrong? I'm actually not too sure what the form of $(\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z})^{99}$ actually takes... I don't think it's a direct product of $(\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z})$ 99 times, so just $[g_1] + ... + [g_{99}]$, where each $g_i \in  (\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z})$? If that's case, the answer should be the same as in a).

Comment: @mathstudent555 it is indeed a direct product but I'm not particularly familiar with that notation. beyond that you can try my answer and it even applies to part (a) :)

Comment: Thanks again. I was a little confused by the notation... If that's the case, would it just $7^{99}-1$? (any combination of elements that have order 7 or 1 except $(1,1,...,1)$.

Comment: @mathstudent555 this is the part where you are ignoring my answer.